# How to count the number of zeros in a list?

Tags: scheme

I'm new to Scheme, so can anyone give me an example? There's no local variable in Scheme, so how can I keep track of the number of zeros that being encountered.

I tried

```
#lang scheme
(define zeroes
  (lambda (ll)
    (cond ((null? ll) 
           0)
          (else (= 0 (car ll))))
    (zeroes (cdr ll))
  )
)
```

But the compiler complained:

```
cdr: expects argument of type <pair>; given ()
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my solution (since the OP's already posted theirs):

```
(define (count-zeroes lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst)
             (count 0))
    (cond ((null? lst) count)
          ((zero? (car lst)) (loop (cdr lst) (+ count 1)))
          (else (loop (cdr lst) count)))))
```

Of course, no treatment of this subject can be considered complete without talking about `fold`, which is usually used to "summarise" a list down to a single object (like we're doing for this question):

```
(define (count-zeroes lst)
  (fold (lambda (elem count)
          (if (zero? elem) (+ count 1) count))
        0 lst))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just figured out the solution,

```
(define count
  (lambda (lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) 0)
          ((= 0 (car lst)) (+ 1 (count (cdr lst))))
          (else (+ 0 (count (cdr lst))))
    )      
  )
)
```

Comment: That's good news. :-) Three things: 1. You can use `zero?` to check whether something is zero. 2. Please format your code in Scheme style, not C style. ;-) (More specifically, don't have dangling brackets.) 3. You can use `(else (count (cdr lst)))`, without adding 0. :-)

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: First, thanks for the comment. However, Scheme style hurt my eyes a bit. I felt extremely uncomfortable while matching those parentheses in my head.

Comment: If you're matching brackets in your head, you're doing it wrong! :-) Most experienced Schemers like to use something like [Paredit](http://mumble.net/~campbell/emacs/paredit.html) to handle the brackets for them. (In Paredit, brackets are _never_ mismatched---the program handles ensuring that all open brackets are matched with a closing one.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm keeping this at a hint level for now.

Your function is doing two things. First it computes 0 if its argument is an empty list, or #t or #f if its argument is a list that begins with 0 or not. Then it throws that result out and calls itself recursively on the rest of the list.

You're going to have to do two things to make this work: 1) combine the results of the individual zero tests somehow (for a thought experiment, look at your code; how would it ever return the value 2 if the list had two zeroes?); 2) "bottom out" successfully when it calls itself recursively on an empty list.

Comment: I understand the logic, the hard part was the sugar syntax of scheme :(. A similar example would be a greater hint in this case.